# Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" Exercise 1.10 - Generalization

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

> *Exercise*:
> Suppose that $\mu(X) < +\infty$, $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of **bounded** complex measurable functions on $X$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$. Prove that:
> $$ \lim _{n \to +\infty} \int _X f_n d\mu = \int _X f d\mu $$

Now, I noticed that
$$\text{bounded} \hspace{2mm} f_n, \hspace{3mm} \mu(X)<+\infty \implies f_n \in L^1(\mu)$$
therefore I tried to prove the theorem by replacing **boundedness** with **$f_n \in L^1(\mu)$**.

*Proof*:
By uniform convergence on $X$ and by $\mu(X)<+\infty$, it is easy to see that $f \in L^1(\mu)$:
$$\exists N: |f| \leq |f-f_N| + |f_N| \leq 1 + |f_N| \hspace{2mm} \text{in X} \implies \int _X |f| d\mu \leq \mu(X) + \int _X |f_N| d\mu < +\infty$$
Moreover, the uniform convergence implies that:
$$\exists M: \forall n \geq M, |f-f_n| \leq 1 \hspace{2mm} \text{in X}$$
so that the sequence $(|f-f_n|)_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions dominated by an $L^1(\mu)$ function (namely the constant $1$ because $\mu(X) < +\infty$); hence we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem:
$$ |f-f_n| \to 0 \hspace{2mm} \text{in X} \implies \lim _{n \to +\infty} \int _{X} |f-f_n| d\mu = 0$$
Finally, since both $f$ and $f_n$ belong to $L^1(\mu)$, we can apply the following inequality:
$$ \left| \int _X f - \int _X f_n \right| d\mu \leq \int _X |f-f_n| d\mu$$
which, together with the previous result, after a proper rearrengement yields:
$$ \lim _{n \to +\infty} \int _X f_n d\mu = \int _X f d\mu $$
as desired.

It is clear that $\mu(X)<+\infty$ is essential to the proof and thus I guess also to the statement itself. For this reason I asked myself what would happen without this condition. If I require boundedness as in the original statement, then there is an easy counter-example:
$$ f_n = \frac{1}{n}, \hspace{2mm} \text{$\mu$ counting measure on infinite X} $$
however I couldn't find a counter-example in the case in which I require $f_n \in L^1(\mu)$. Does anyone know such a counter-example? In general, what can we say if we have a sequence of Lebesgue Measurable functions?

Comment: $f_n=\frac 1n 1_{(n,2n)}, f=0$ (Lebesgue mesure).

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed. If you want to post it as an answer I will surely accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counter-example is $f_n=\frac 1 n 1_{(n,2n)}, f=0$ on $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue mesure.